# Need a book on Algebra but having these properties for self study and beginner

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I have recently read a book called *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen D. Abbott
. I really liked that book because of scratch work for proof of theorems he had presented before going over to formal proof. I would like to read similar text for modern algebra too. Can anyone suggest some book in similar to essence of Stephen D. Abbott's book. Mainly that book should tell you why author is doing theorems like that or what is idea behind it.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps [**A First Course in Abstract Algebra**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201763907) by John B. Fraleigh.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks